# Hi I'm a C newbie. (swap the row of matrix)

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, swap

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

void swap_mat(int** ppMat, int i, int j);

int main(void) {

    int mat[][3] = { {2,4,6},{8,10,12},{14,16,18} };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    swap_mat((int**)mat, 0, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void swap_mat(int** ppMat, int i, int j) {


    {
        int* pTmp;
        
        pTmp = ppMat[i];
        ppMat[i] = ppMat[j];
        ppMat[j] = pTmp;
    
        }
}
```

i had got a matrix.

```
2 4 6
8 10 12
14 16 18
```

i want to swap 1row 2row. like

```
8 10 12
2 4 6
14 16 18
```

but i got the result that is

```
6 8 2
4 10 12
14 16 18
```

.
i am devastated now..
can you help me please?

Comment: You can't move the whole row like this, you have to move the elements one at a time, or use memcpy to move whole rows at a time. I suggest you use a for loop in swap_mat(), but with only 3 elements on each row you could leave it unrolled.

Answer (score 1):

You may not just swap whole arrays without swapping their elements sequentially.

If you want to swap two rows of a two-dimensional array then the function `swap_mat` can look like

```
void swap_mat( int *a, int *b, size_t n ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = b[i];
        b[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

and the function is called like

```
swap_mat( mat[0], mat[1], 3 );
```

or like

```
swap_mat( mat[0], mat[1], sizeof( mat[0] ) / sizeof( *mat[0] ) );
```

As for your function definition then as in the used by you system `sizeof( int * )` is equal to `8` then you have that for example the expression `ppMat[0]` yields a value that is internally represented as pair `{ 2, 4 }`  while the expression `ppMat[1]` is represented internally as pair `{ 6, 8 }` that the function tries to swap.

Comment: @mapocorin If the problem is resolved then select the best answer to close the question and your reputation will be increased.